# Rename spring-data-rest's search path

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, hal

I would like to know how I can rename (use a country specific translation) the `/search` path in Spring Data Rest endpoints. I found this class `RepositorySearchController` with hardcoded String's. Is this the place? And is there a way to configure this? Or override it in some way? Maybe using filters?

Comment: Ok, the existing question/answer tells me what I found out: It is not possible to configure the naming of this path.\

Comment: However, it does not tell me if Filter's will help.